# Make Windows Vista hibernate when idle

Tags: windows, windows-vista, hibernate

I'm using Windows Vista, and I want to make the computer hibernate or sleep when left idle for a set period of time (for example, 20 minutes). What are the steps for accomplishing this?

Comment: Modify the advanced power saving settings under Control Panel to set your timeout to 20 minutes, and the sleep mode to hibernate. Several questions on this site address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to 
Control Panel --> All Control Panel Items --> Power Options

There in the plan selected, click Change Plan Settings. Now click Change Advanced Power settings.

[image]

Change the value of Sleep or Hibernate.

Comment: Does the same apply to Windows 7, or are different steps involved?

Comment: DO not worry, the same steps apply to windows 7 also